# Select missing rows using SQL LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table like the following

```
RoleId      Roles
------------------------------------------
  1         Administrators Viewers Users Managers 
  2         Administrators Viewers Managers 
  3         Administrators
  4         Viewers
```

I need to get the `RoleId`'s based on the roles. I have each role as a string.

So when I use the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Roles 
WHERE Roles like '%Administrators Viewers Managers%'
```

I get only the first two rows

```
RoleId      Roles
--------------------------------------------------
  1         Administrators Viewers Users Managers 
  2         Administrators Viewers Managers
```

But I need it to fetch the remaining rows too since it contains `Administrators` and `Viewers`.
I am actually using an Stored procedure to supply the roles as a parameter. So it is not always the same. **Its dynamic**. I cant use OR. I need a solution that will work for any parameter.

Is there a combination between `IN` and `LIKE` clause ?

Or how can I proceed

Comment: hmmm this is an interested method, but doesnt seem like a good long-term solution. i think ideally you would have 2 tables which would allow you to be more flexible later... ie. Roles, and Permissions... ie.  `ROLES TABLE: roleID 1=Admin, roleID 2=Viewer`  

`PERMISSIONS TABLE: roleID=1, view=yes, admin=yes, edit=yes; roleId=2, view=yes, admin=no, edit=no`. Then you would be able to do more complex queries.

Comment: How can you get row 1 with that query?

Comment: The script provided above would not bring back record 'Administrators Viewers Users Managers' as 'Users' is not specified in your LIKE clause. If your parameter is dynamic, I would suggest DSQL. Declare a parameter with writes out your query and execute. I am not sure how you are going to break your parameter up into 3 (Administrator / Viewers / Managers) variables though.

Comment: I think you need to do some research on relational databases. Your approach is wrong so unless you have a good reason to do it like that then you need to rethink it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Roles 
WHERE Roles like '%Administrators%'
OR    Roles like '%Viewers%'
```

Comment: I am actually using an Stored procedure to supply the roles as a parameter. So it is not always the same. Its dynamic.

Comment: @Targarian: so what type is the parameter? I would normalize your table. Create another table to store the "Sub-Roles" which belong to a role.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *   FROM Roles 
WHERE Roles like '%Administrators%'  OR    Roles like '%Viewers%' 
OR Roles like '%Administrators Viewers%'
```

Comment: Could you add some additional information along with your answer?

Comment: Isn't the third LIKE completely redundant due to the first two?

Answer (score 0):

If you `dynamically` pass the `roles` as a parameter use like the below Query
for

**SQL Server 2000 and above**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Roles 
WHERE Roles like '%'+@Roles+'%'
```

**SQL Server 2008 and above**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Roles 
WHERE Contains(Roles,@Roles)
```

but the above query will produce the result only based on the `roles` you have passed